# Can RocketMQ producer send message with mutiple tags?

Tags: rocketmq

RocketMQ consumers can subscribe topic with multiple tags like this

```
consumer.subscribe("topic", "taga||tagb");
```

How can producers send messages with both `taga` and `tagb`

I have try to send message with tags "taga||tagb", but the consumer does not receive any message. When I query message by the msg_id, the tags is `[taga||tagb]`, not ["taga", "tagb"]

```
Topic:               handy_test
Tags:                [taga||tagb]
Keys:                [key_1491988576642]
Queue ID:            0
Queue Offset:        215
CommitLog Offset:    36094
Reconsume Times:     0
Born Timestamp:      2017-04-12 17:16:16,645
Store Timestamp:     2017-04-12 17:16:25,316
Born Host:           10.1.101.16:33421
Store Host:          10.116.22.25:10911
System Flag:         0
Properties:          {TAGS=taga||tagb, KEYS=key_1491988576642}
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently, sending with multiple tags is not supported.

While subscribe for multiple tags is ok.